# Webview flutter for education notification

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, mobile-development

I want to make a webview application. The first page has a login section. On the second page, the course scores are written. I want to receive notifications as the scores are announced. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several plugins for this but Personality I prefer this one

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin/example

its more flexible. And it has more functionalities.

To me its the best.

Comment: Thank you, you helped a lot

Comment: Okey. Mark, it answered.
In case you need a helping hand you can contact me on theodoreimonigie@gmail.com or https://join.skype.com/invite/ntjGAbyMAbsN